# IValueConverter not working in blend design

Tags: data-binding, ivalueconverter, expression-blend-4

I am using Blend 4. I am having a list item which i am binding to sample dataset VM using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335667/providing-designtime-viewmodel-data-for-blend-and-vs), which works fine. The issue is with the IValueConverter applied to binding. Blend doesn't seem to process the converter in design time UI. Is it possible for Blend to process data using converters in design time?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per-se but it might still help you.

What I do in these situations is stick a breakpoint in the Convert method, attach the debugger to Blend.exe and open the offending Xaml (in Blend).  It's a real nice trick for solving some of these blendability issues.

HTH.